# Site shows 20px padding on iPhone & iPad

Tags: html, iphone, css, ipad, mobile

I have created a test page for my website that strips out almost everything and still cannot get rid of the 20px or so padding on iPhone or iPad.

Please see test page at https://lacrafts.worldsecuresystems.com/test.

I have tried media styles, removing padding etc.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<body id="sub_body" data-twttr-rendered="true">
     <div id="site_wrap" class="clearfix">
          <div id="header-wrap" class="clearfix">
            <div id="header" class="clearfix">dasd<br>fdsfds<br>jhkljklj<br></div>
     </div>
</body>
```

Here are the relevant HTML styles:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:Calibri, Tahoma;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#1d1d1d;
    background:#ee2505;
    font-weight:regular;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#site_wrap {
    border-top:8px solid #1d1d1d;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#header-wrap {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#header {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

/* *********************** CLEARFIX **************************** */

.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}
* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced problems like this on mobile developments. I found it useful to add to my pages a div wrapping the whole content, and set it's style to:

```
{
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
}
```